# iOS app built from xcode but not showing build in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, build, app-store-connect

I have built an iOS app and trying to update the version and upload it to AppStore. Its getting uploaded from **Xcode** and am getting the success message. But i could not find the build in **itunesconnect**. For a while its shown in **activity** tab with **processing** status but while refreshing it gets disappeared.

Comment: Did you get the email from Apple telling you that it has finished processing? The build won't appear in iTunes Connect until you get that email.

Comment: No i didnt receive any mail, i have uploaded it again but its showing that a binary already exist with the built version. So i updated the version and uploaded them again. Still the same result.

Comment: I received a mail stating that Your app "App Name" (Apple ID: xxxxxxx) has one or more issues. But nothing explained with that.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue - I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Sometime, its will takes time to appeared on ITC.
Still it not seen on ITC, then please upload one more time using Application Loader but change the build version.

Lets try it

Comment: i uploaded it again but its showing that a binary already exist with the built version. So i updated the version and uploaded them again. Tried with Application loader too. Same issue still.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually my app had watch extensions which was not removed properly. So once i removed them from "Build Phases" -> "Embed Watch Content"it got solved.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure your Info.plist has all the keys that you're trying to access.**

I had the same issue on Friday. Submission was successful, but then I was waiting for hours, tried Application Loader, changing version number, all with no luck.

A day later got email from Apple:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "MyAppName". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an  NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

In case (like me) you're using Appcelerator, there was a bug in 5.5.1 resolved in 6.0.0. [Find out more about it here](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23925)

Comment: I received a mail stating that Your app "App Name" (Apple ID: xxxxxxx) has one or more issues. But nothing explained with that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually my app had watch extensions which was not removed properly. So once i removed them from "Build Phases" -> "Embed Watch Content"it got solved.

Answer (score 0):

‌I had exactly the same problem. On the 3rd rebuild after a version number change while it was uploading I watched the iTunes Connect ->Activity->All Builds page. It appeared there 'processing' for 2 minutes. It then disappeared. However I then got an email from Apple telling me that it had been rejected because it uses the camera and photo library. iOS 10 has stricter control of privacy issues. It only requires a string against the correct key in the .plist to resolve - the keys are of the type 'NSPhotoLibraryUseageDescription'  (or 'Privacy - Photo Library Useage Description' depending on how the plist is viewed).

It is extremely frustrating that the first two uploads did not result in any message from Apple - why cant they keep the build on the Activity page with some info about the reason it failed? Why do they not send an email every time they reject a build? I have wasted an entire day on this!

If you are suffering from this issue, have a think about what you are accessing and see if there is an appropriate privacy useage description string you can add to your plist. I see from various forums that some frameworks ask for a whole raft of permissions that you may not think your app needs - try adding every privacy useage description temporarily to see if that resolves the problem

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually my app had watch extensions which was not removed properly. So once i removed them from "Build Phases" -> "Embed Watch Content"it got solved.

Answer (score 0):

Actually my app had watch extensions which was not removed properly. So once i removed them from "Build Phases" -> "Embed Watch Content", it got solved.